# Edit button for mobile users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, mobile-site

Where's the button to edit my profile on the mobile interface? I want to edit my profile description, but I can't without having the `Edit` button to do so. Can one be added? Or not? If you're wondering what I mean by mobile interface, it's the in-browser mobile interface.

Comment: Same request on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/unable-to-edit-profile-in-mobile-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the recent removal of the dedicated mobile site in favour of a [responsive site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/179041) catering to both mobile and desktop, you can now edit your profile from a mobile device.